# How to re populate data in child component?

Tags: reactjs

I'm having a React component that displays data from an API. At the moment I'm having this ajax call at ComponentDidMount, described [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount).

How do I retrigger the data pull when there is a selection change on the dropdown in the same component since the state update will not trigger the ComponentDidMount ?

Thank you

Comment: Can you show us the code?

Comment: A general answer would be to create a class method to make the request and call that method both in `componentDidMount` and when handling the dropdown selection.

Comment: Hi nem035,

agreed, why such aproach didnt come through my mind :)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use componentDidUpdate

React doc https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate:

componentDidUpdate() is invoked immediately after updating occurs. This method is not called for the initial render.

Use this as an opportunity to operate on the DOM when the component has been updated. This is also a good place to do network requests as long as you compare the current props to previous props (e.g. a network request may not be necessary if the props have not changed).

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  // Typical usage (don't forget to compare props):
  if (this.props.selectedMenuItem !== prevProps.selectedMenuItem) {
    this.fetchData(this.props.userID);
  }
}
```

Comment: this is a good example to follow on using React lifecycle methods.

Comment: Hi Pavel and Sultan,

I think I'll give this approach a try and hopefully it works. Seems like the ComoponentDidUpdate will work together with ShouldComponentUpdate if some logic or checking is required.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to the component re-render, you have to setState after fetching the data in the componentDidMount().
For example:

```
componentDidMount(){
const options = fetch( ...); //store your data here
this.setState({options})
}
```

And in the component you can use the state the populate the data:

For example your Dropdown button:

```
export default class OutlineButton extends React.Component {
render() {
return (

      <ButtonDropdown isOpen={this.state.dropdownOpen} toggle={this.toggle}>
        <DropdownToggle size = 'md' color='#58b7e6' caret className={styles.button} > {this.state.name}</DropdownToggle>
        <DropdownMenu className={styles.drowDownButton} styles={{}}>
          {this.state.options.map((option, i) => (
            <DropdownItem key={i} onClick={this.handleClick} value={option}>
              {option}
            </DropdownItem>
          ))}
        </DropdownMenu>
      </ButtonDropdown>
    );
  }
}
```

The code above use reactstrap

Comment: Hi,
I dont think the code above will trigger the fetch in componentDidMount since state update will triggger render but not ComponentDidMount.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to stick with React lifecycle methods, you can have a function that triggers the AJAX fetch request, such like:

```
handleSelectionChange = () {
  this.fetchData(this.state.selectedOption);
}
```

This would be passed as a callback function to the `onChange` method attribute on your DropDown component.